# restcountries api show after hot reload in flutter

Tags: api, flutter

I use in rest-countries API to build app of countries name and flag in flutter.

when i build the app is not show me the data from API.

but when i do save or hot hot reload the data show.

i use  initState() but is still don't help.

and i insert the name and flag of all countries in list and show them in ListView.builder.

[after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5WnB.jpg)

[after save or hot reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l1u3.jpg)

main

```
List<String> countriesName = [];
List<String> countriesFlag = [];
NetWork netWork = NetWork();
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      getNetwork();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  Future getNetwork() async {
    countriesName = await netWork.getAllCountries();
    countriesFlag = await netWork.getAllCountriesFlag();
  }
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: countriesName.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      '${countriesName[index]}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Hero(
                      tag: 'flag $index',
                      child: SvgPicture.network(
                        '${countriesFlag[index]}', //'https://restcountries.eu/data/gtm.svg'
                        width: 30,
                        height: 120,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => CountryDetail(
                                    countriesFlag: countriesFlag,
                                    countriesName: countriesName,
                                    index: index,
                                    netWork: netWork,
                                  )),
                        );
```

network

```
final urlall = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';
class NetWork {
  Future getAllCountries() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(urlall);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jasonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<String> countriesName = [];
        for (var country in jasonData) {
          countriesName.add(country['name']);
        }
        return countriesName;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('e => $e');
    }
  }
  Future getAllCountriesFlag() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(urlall);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jasonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<String> countriesFlag = [];
        for (var flag in jasonData) {
          countriesFlag.add(flag['flag']);
        }
        return countriesFlag;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('e => $e');
  }
  }
}
```

-------solution--------

i find the solution.

```
  Future getNetwork() async {
    countriesName = await netWork.getAllCountries();
    countriesFlag = await netWork.getAllCountriesFlag();
    setState(() {});  // added line
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but the way I call API in flutter would be similar to this:

```
List<String> countriesName = [];
List<String> countriesFlag = [];

NetWork netWork = NetWork();
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getNetwork();
  }
  Future getNetwork() async {
    setState(() {
      countriesName = await netWork.getAllCountries();
      countriesFlag = await netWork.getAllCountriesFlag();
    });
  }
  // Build UI code here
```

You should then check if the value is null for countriesName and countriesFlag then display the data when the API returns a response.

Hope this helps you in some way.